# How to autocomplete when source code becomes invalid after user input?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension offering autocompletion for a customized language. It intends to auto suggest based on what user is typing, using info from the compiler, e.g., previously defined variables. However, after user inputs, the source code often becomes invalid and contains syntax error. The compiler fails to parse it and thus cannot offer defined variables, which were available before user inputs. How to handle this kind of incremental change? Does such autocompletion require the compiler to tolerate errors to some extent? There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220099/how-does-code-completion-work), but is too broad and not conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

A parser is not the right tool for code completion, because it requires syntactically correct input, which is almost never available when code completion is required. You could of course cache info from a previous parse run and update this only when the code reaches a valid state from time to time, but this is not going to work well. What would you show when the user just started to write the code (since there was no previous good run)?

Instead I used a different approach in my Code Completion Core for ANTLR4 ([antlr4-c3](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3)): I use the provied ATN ([Augmented Transition Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_transition_network)) to find the current caret position and then look ahead to possible tokens that could follow. This gives you already all possible lexems (numbers, IDs, keywords etc.). If you want to give more details (e.g. class names, variables etc.) a bit more processing is required.

By using a manual walk over the ATN you can at least handle partially correct code. An important requirement is that the code from the beginning until the caret position must be correct, but everything after that can be imperfect.

I use this code completion core for my vscode extension [vscode-antlr4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4), where it works pretty well.