# How does code completion actually work when it comes to finding libraries?

Tags: algorithm

I've found this excellent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220099/how-does-code-completion-work) detailing how code completion algorithms tend to work. What I'm confused about, however, is how they efficiently find a non-local class, function, or variable.

For example, when I begin to type "List" into IntelliJ Idea, it immediately suggests the List class from java.util.List. Where does it actually store this list of java modules, classes and their member functions? Does it not take up a lot of memory? In addition, it also seems to store the arguments and return values as well. Is there an efficient algorithm to store and find these?

I assume a similar thing would work for user-defined modules, just using a dynamic storage model instead of a static one. If such a storage model does exist, are there downloads on the internet for these files?

Comment: When you open a project, notice that IntelliJ says it is "indexing" your files. I assume that the indexes it builds (on disk, likely also (partially?) cached in memory) provide the information autocompletion needs. I would expect the size of this to be roughly proportional to the size of the program. As it is currently phrased, I believe this question is too broad to be well-answerable - I can only speculate, but I would expect that IntelliJ employs a variety of data structures, from "standard" key-value indexes like B-Trees or hash tables, to more specific prefix or suffix trees etc...

Comment: "A lot of memory" is a rather subjective thing. When your development system probably has at least 4 gigabytes of RAM, the few megabytes taken up by class names and such to facilitate auto completion is not a major concern.